# Firestore how to get organized random key?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I just migrated my data from Realtime Database to Firestore and started to use firestore but I had a function to push() in Realtime Database and also save push().key so I changed it to add() or set() for Firestore but I realize that add().id set().id is totally random key unlike Realtime Database push().key is organized like the later push().key is always behind previous push().key. I must save data and it must be organized like push(). Is there any solution to generate keys that are organized like push().key??

```
//I tried 2 options

//option 1
ref.add({something:something}).then((gref)=>{ref.doc(gref.id).set({key:gref.id},{merge:true})})

//option 2
var ref = db.doc();
ref.set({something:something,key:ref.id})
```

both generates unorganized keys unlike push().key

Answer (score 0):

I searched, read documents and I realized that Firestore doesn't provide organized key as Realtime Database but I found solution for this. If someone need organized key, you have to use timestamp and sort as ascending or descending.
just like

```
// when you want to save data..
ref.set({timestamp:firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()})
// and if you want get data..
db.collection('something').orderBy("timestamp", "asc").get()
// it will sort automatically!
```